# How to force get the latest tasks by Work Management Service Application?

Tags: tasks

I already created a webpart which getting all tasks from current user cross-site. It works and I see the same tasks as in the task list on my mysite. I only see the tasks list in my webpart is not getting the latest tasks. It gets only the tasks which are loaded in the mysite task list.

When I go to the mysite task list I see it is refreshing and gets the latest tasks. So there is some logic on this page which is forcing getting all tasks.

How can I do the same in my webpart code?

```
private void ShowMyTasks()
        {
            // Get current context
            var context = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext.Current;

            // Gets the session manager
            UserSettingsManager usm = new UserSettingsManager(context);
            Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.UserOrderedSessionManager osm = new UserOrderedSessionManager(context);

            UserOrderedSession uos = osm.CreateSession();

            // Create a new task query
            Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.TaskQuery tq = new TaskQuery();

            // Set completed filter
            var taskFilter = new TaskFilter()
            {
                CompletedCriterion = new BooleanCriterion() { CompareType = BooleanCompareType.IsFalse }
            };

            tq.FieldFilter = taskFilter;

            // Read filtered tasks from the task session

            TaskClientCollection tcc = uos.ReadTasks(tq);

            // Set datasource and bind
            taskRepeater.DataSource = tcc;
            taskRepeater.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is way too much code to simply copy&paste it into here, so please check this Microsoft [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2014/03/31/work-management-service-in-sharepoint-2013-a-short-overview-for-developers.aspx) which hopefully will remain in place and see the section: "Working with provider refreshes". This should offer you the functionality to refresh the tasks.

Comment: Do I missing this code?? CreateRefreshJobResult refreshResult = uos.BeginCacheRefresh();